# Pushing rails app to heroku "failed unexpectedly"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

Been pushing this rails app 3.2.13 with ruby version 1.8.4

I already ran "rvm install ruby ruby-1.8.4"

Changed my gemfile to include:
ruby '1.8.4'

Here's terminal error:

```
ggeorgiev@ubuntu:~/projects/webshop$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 5, done.
elta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 323 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
 !
 !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/ruby-1.8.4.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf -' failed unexpectedly:
 !     
 !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
 !     tar: Child returned status 1
  !     tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:fathomless-sierra-3921.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fathomless-sierra-3921.git'
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please switch to a newer Ruby version. Even the ancient 1.8.7 is no longer supported for a while now...

Comment: I am getting this error on Ruby 2.2.0-dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.2.0 was giving me trouble, try using Ruby 2.1.0 and specify it in your gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    ruby '2.1.0'
```